# Text-based interface for PostgreSQL?

Tags: command-line, postgresql, tools

I know that `psql` is an option, but I'm looking for an easier text-based interface for PostgreSQL. Something that's similar to what 'tig' is to 'git', or 'phpmyadmin' is to 'mysql' (but using the command line). does any one know something like this?

Comment: What do you mean by _'SQL is an option'_?

Comment: I mean that I can use `psql` to write queries and see the results, but that's not what I want. I'm looking for an application that allows me to explore the DBs from the terminal without writing SQL statements.

Comment: I am afraid I've never heard about such a tool...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do that `psql` cannot accomplish? I also never heard a similar tool, at least not one better than `psql` (which is the most advanced/powerful prompt tool of all SGDBs I've ever used)...

Comment: There is a phpPgAdmin and there are tons of other GUI tools: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools but I doubt you'll find anything that works on the console (i.e. non-graphical)

Comment: @TinyProton, please define "explore the DBs"... Because `psql` can "explore the DBs" on a lot of ways with no need of SQL statements, perhaps you just don't know it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html), which is Postgres' command line tool.

Comment: I don't think he is, he's looking for something that's more of a curses interface. think, he wants `top` instead of `ps`.

Comment: No that's not what I'm looking for, sorry for not being clear. I want something that would allow me to explore the DBs without writing SQL statements.

Comment: you can do this with psql, actually @TinyProton.  See the \d commands.  Use \? for a list.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly nine years late (hahaha) but I've just seen this:

[Rust TUI for PostgreSQL](https://rustrepo.com/repo/TaKO8Ki-gobang-rust-database-interfaces)